# How do I check the reason for my being banned in Battle.net?

Tags: starcraft-2, battle.net

I've been banned from the Battle.net servers.

A pop-up window said 'The detail has been sent to your registered e-mail address', but I've got nothing.

**How do I check the reason for my being banned?**

Comment: And you are sure there arent any reason to your ban? Even minor threats in game can leet to a ban. And note that I have absolutly no respect for such behavior.

Comment: Watch out, we got a badass over here xD

Comment: @AtlasEU This section is not for judging, it's for comments that are relevant to the question being asked.

Comment: @Kevin It sure is - my bad!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ban details are typically sent to the email registered at Battle.net

Wait a bit and check your spam folder.

If you have waited, contact [Battle.net support](https://us.battle.net/support/en/ticket/submit). They should be able to tell you why you were banned.

Here is also their support page regarding [disabled, banned or locked accounts](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/account-disabled-banned-or-locked).

Comment: I've been waiting for a month. I was playing in America server back then, and got banned. And today, I've banned from Korea, Europe, SEA server at the same time. NO single Email from Blizzard. Also checked spam folder but nothing. I'll contact support.

Comment: @asdf Contacting support is your best bet. You should also log into your Battle.net account and verify that they have the correct email address on file and that you are correctly receiving mail sent to that exact address. I also recommend attaching an authenticator to your account in the future if you have not done so as there is also the possibility of your account having been hacked which could lead to such unexpected bans.

Answer (score 0):

Wait a few more hours. If there is still no email contact Blizzard via their website. Go to support and send a ticket with your problem.